# mysqli - possible to get insert_id of two previous queries in transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, transactions

Is it possible to get the insert_id of the previous two queries? I am able to get the last one, but would like the previous two. In the below example, once the form in processed, I would like to add a new role to the address table, new row to the role table then add a row to the customers using the id's from the queries inserted in the previous two queries. Is this at all possible.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) :
  $username = $_POST["username"];
  $password = $_POST["password"];
  $role = $_POST["role"];
  $permission1 = intval($_POST["permission1"]);
  $permission2 = intval($_POST["permission2"]);
  $city = $_POST["city"];
  $state = $_POST["state"];
  mysqli_autocommit($connection,FALSE);
  mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO Address(city, state) VALUES('{$city}', '{$state}')");
  mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO Roles(roleName, permission1, permission2) VALUES('{$role}', '{$permission1}', '{$permission2}')");
  mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO Customers(username, password, roleId, addressId) VALUES ('{$username}', '{$password}'," .  mysqli_insert_id($connection) . " , " . mysqli_insert_id($connection) . ")");
  if(mysqli_error($connection)):
    echo mysqli_error($connection);
  endif;
  mysqli_commit($connection);
endif;
```

The `mysqli_insert_id($connection)` in the last query will pull the Id from the `Roles` insert twice. Any way to get it to grab the two Id vals from the first two queries?

Comment: No, it gets the last inserted id as it says on the tin. Call it after each query you want the id of and store in a variable.

Comment: Just save it as a variable. `/* execute first query */ $id1 = mysqli_insert_id($connection); /* execute second query */ $id2 = mysqli_insert_id($connection);`

Comment: Thanks! New to this stuff so didn't know if the insert_id function would fail if put outside of a query.

Comment: Why would you think that a function would work differently depending on whether you're assigning the result to a variable or using it as part of a concatenation? A function is a function, it just returns a value and you can use that value any way you want.

Comment: @TaylorFoster It doesn't fail if put outside of a query.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) :
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$role = $_POST["role"];
$permission1 = intval($_POST["permission1"]);
$permission2 = intval($_POST["permission2"]);
$city = $_POST["city"];
$state = $_POST["state"];
mysqli_autocommit($connection,FALSE);

mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO Address(city, state) VALUES('{$city}', '{$state}')");
//this will give you first id//
$first_inserted_id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);

mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO Roles(roleName, permission1, permission2) VALUES('{$role}', '{$permission1}', '{$permission2}')");
//this will give you second id//
$second_inserted_id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);

mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO Customers(username, password, roleId, addressId) VALUES ('{$username}', '{$password}'," .    $first_inserted_id  . " , " . $second_inserted_id . ")");

//this will give you third id//
$third_inserted_id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);

if(mysqli_error($connection)):
    echo mysqli_error($connection);
endif;
    mysqli_commit($connection);
endif;
```

Comment: Generally you should provide some text explaining your answer, not just code. Also you're not using `$first_inserted_id` or `$second_inserted_id` anywhere.